# How to mark a form as "Dirty" using form name in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, typescript

I am trying to add some html elements dynamically in a form. When I click a button, these elements are added properly inside that html form. Below is my html form declaration.

```
<div ng-cloak ng-form="" name="jobEntryForm" id="jobEntryForm" job-entry-layout confirm-on-exit ng-hide="vm.showEstimateContacts">
<!-- other elements here-->
</div>
```

And inside this `div`, I am adding dynamic html elements like below:

```
<div class="col-md-2 pull-left ">
  <div ng-include="'/App/Job/Entry/tasksMenuButton.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Although the html elements inside `tasksMenuButton.html` are added dynamically, they do not belong to any directive. This `tasksMenuButton.html` also have some dynamic elements (i.e. consignment task) which are added using `ng-include` directive. Now to handle **consignment task**'s functionality, I have created separate controller (i.e. consignmentTask.controller.ts). Now what I want is to set the form `jobEntryForm` as dirty from inside this controller. But I can't access the form. The controller doesn't have any property to hold the form. Below is the scope interface:

```
export interface IConsigmentTaskScope extends ng.IScope {
        task: IConsignmentTask;
        contactEntryModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
        serviceListModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
        messageModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
    }
```

How can I get the form **jobEntryForm** inside this (consignmentTask.controller.ts) controller and make it Dirty?

** I tried to get form elements using there id/class but the element(s) contains a form attribute as null.

Comment: Why are you trying to manually mark the form as dirty? Typically you have the form elements update the form dirty and validity.

Comment: @BryanEuton Inside my consignmentTask.html page, I have a dropdown list to populate some service information. Whenever, I select/change any service, I want to mark the form as dirty so that the user realizes that form needs to be saved.

Comment: Try giving the ngform a name.  I'm not at a computer to check this, but I think that's why it isn't working for you automatically when you change the select.  If this doesn't work, please post the html for the snippet with the select in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define **jobEntryForm** on the scope:

```
export interface IConsigmentTaskScope extends ng.IScope {
    task: IConsignmentTask;
    contactEntryModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
    serviceListModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
    messageModalInstance: ModalServiceInstance;
    jobEntryForm: ng.IFormController
}
```

And then call `$scope.jobEntryForm.$setDirty()`